# $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+99$, $f(100)=101$, find $f(7)$.

Tags: functions, contest-math

**Question :**

> Let $f:\mathbb{Q} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, and $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+99$, $f(100)=101$, find $f(7)$.

**Attempts :**

I am pretty sure this is one of those questions which require an amazingly genius solution. However after having tried for half an hour, I still couldn’t get a clue. My problem is that I don’t really know how $f(7)$ can show up.

What I know:

- $f(100)=2f(50)+99 \Longrightarrow f(50)=1$
- $f(50)=2f(25)+99 \Longrightarrow f(25)=-49$
- $f(x)=f(x)+f(0)+99 \Longrightarrow f(0)=-99$

From here I want to break it down to smaller numbers, but I can’t find a way. Any suggestions or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(x)+99$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.  Show that $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$.  Use this to verify that there exists $k\in\mathbb{Q}$ for which $f(x)=kx$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, and then for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+99$. Then $g(100)=200$ and
$$ g(x+y)=f(x+y)+99=f(x)+f(y)+2\cdot 99 = g(x)+g(y).$$
With $x=y=0$, find $g(0)=0$.
Then note that $g(n+1)=g(n)+g(1)$ and conclude $g(n)=ng(1)$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Amazing......just amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f(1)=A$.

Then:
$$f(2)=2f(1)+99=2A+99$$
$$f(3)=f(2)+f(1)=3A+198$$
$$f(4)=f(1)+f(3)+99=4A+3(99)$$

We are given the general rule that for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f(n)=nA+99(n-1)$.  We can plug in $n=100$ and get that $101=100A+99^2$, which gives that $A=-97$.  Then, substituting $n=7$, we have that $f(7)=7(-97)+6\cdot99=-85$

Comment: This is easy to understand as well. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

putting $x=0,y=0 $ in original equation,$f(0)=-99$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.....(1)$

using $f(x+h)=f(x)+f(h)+99$  in (1)

thus we have  $f'(x)=f'(0)=k$

integrating

$f(x)=kx+m$ using condition $f(0)=-99$ and $f(100)=101$ we can find $k,m$

can you do the rest?